# How do I set alarm before specific time in android studio?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My codes

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);

    long eventTime=calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    long oneDay=AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
    int noOfDays=4;
    long reminderTime=eventTime-(noOfDays*oneDay);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Home.this, MyBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Home.this, 0, myIntent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderTime, pendingIntent);
```

I tried everything but It will ring right on I setting it !

Comment: So based off what I can tell from your code, it seems like you are setting the alarm to be at reminderTime which is when the eventtime - 4 days? Could it be that you are setting an alarm that is 4 days away?

Comment: Use Gregorian calender Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: I'm getting the eventTime with DatePickerDialog , and I want it to remind me before 4 days, before the actual eventTime

Comment: @Prashant.J Thank you It works

Comment: I will add this as an answer to this question. Please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Gregorian calendar,

```
Gregorian calender Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```